# Android Смена текста на время

Tags: java, android, textview, android-animation

У меня есть одна анимация мне нужно пока она срабатывает менять text в TextView, сменить при включении анимации это одно, а как потом сменить обратно? Как возможно отловить конец анимации? или нечто подобное?

Comment: Есть CallBack, когда анимация завершается. Были уже такие вопросы.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei раз такие вопросы были значит я плохо искал, а ссылочку на вопрос можно?

Comment: @Moonwolf45, "android animation callback".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вообщем я сделал то,что надо через callback оказывается весьма полезная вещь
вот код вдруг пригодится:

```
Animation anim_r = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.scale);
anim_r.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim_r) {
            // TODO: Тут действия по началу анимации
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim_r) {
            // TODO: Тут действие по завершению аниации
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim_r) {

        }
    });
```